# Change vars in JS file with grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

Let's say you have a file that contains these 2 vars, but also other content

```
//Other code above
var endpoint='...';
var redirectUrl='...';
//Other code below
```

Now, is there a way for Grunt to change the value of those vars depending on build params?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enclose your line with something easily matchable. (Or if the original values are unique enough, it can be fine as well.)

You can use this plugin:

https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace

To replace it with something else.

Comment: Ah, nice. Thanks. Have you used grunt-replace? Looks easy to use, just interested in reliability.